# display item in ckeditor when i select the item in drop down menu in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a one form in form two field is there one is the  drop down menu and other is ckeditor .i want to do when i select an item from drop down menu that item should display in ckeditor.when i select in second item second item should display in ckeditor how to do i have a searched a lot things but did not get more solution.

```
<td><select  name="template" onChange = "setTemplate(this);">
<option value="0">Admission</option>
<option value="1">Registration</option>
<option value="2">Speech on 2,3 May</option>
</select><script>
    test0 = "";
    test1 = "test string 1";
    test2 = "test string 2";
    function setTemplate(t) {
        var otionValue = t.value;
        if (otionValue == "0") {
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = test0;
        } else if (otionValue == "1")
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = test1;
          else if (otionValue == "2")
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = test2;
    }; </script>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></td>
      </tr
      <tr>
        <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_message; ?></td>
        <td> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js">
```

Comment: What did you tried? So us some code.

Comment: blue112 i have given a code what i wrote

Comment: It looks like there's a type or two here `</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></td>
      </tr
      <tr>` Are you sure that's all ok?